# How to launch Chromium installed with snap with a parameter?

Tags: chromium, raspberrypi, dock

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 for Raspberry Pi 4B 4GB. I'd like to enable hardware video decoding in Chromium and to do that I need to launch Chromium with a parameter "--enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder". Bear in mind that I use Chromium installed with snap, not an apt package.

Ideally, I'd like to launch Chromium with the parameter from Favourites in Ubuntu Dock. How do I do that? I already have a Chromium "shortcut" in the Favourites in the Dock, so how do I edit it to add the parameter?

Comment: Simply `chromium --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder`. But see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1816497; you will need additional parameters, and it is not yet guaranteed to work.

Comment: You are right. Although chrome://gpu shows video decoding is hardware accelerated, in reality it is not.